# Status delete.php function

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking, sql-delete

I have the button working, when I click the X button on my status it takes me to delete.php shows me the link in the browser and the streamitem_id number like so.

Here is the button

```
echo '<a href="mysiteraw/sn-extend/theme/default/delete.php?='.$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].'" onclick="show_confirm() alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="delete">X</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

And the link it gives out

> my site
>   /raw/sn-extend/theme/default/delete.php?=1516

I then see on this page 'cannot find comment' So can anyone help me with the delete.php page please?

Here is my SQL

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
>   `on_streamdata` (   `streamitem_id`
>   int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
>   `streamitem_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `streamitem_creator` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `streamitem_target` int(11) NOT NULL, 
>   `streamitem_timestamp` datetime NOT
>   NULL,   `streamitem_content`
>   varchar(5000) NOT NULL,
>   `streamitem_public` int(11) NOT NULL, 
>   `streamitem_interactionallowed`
>   int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
>   `streamitem_isgroupie` int(11) NOT
>   NULL default '1',   `streamitem_viaid`
>   int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
>   PRIMARY KEY  (`streamitem_id`) )
>   ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
>   AUTO_INCREMENT=1953 ;

And here is my delete.php which is probably completely wrong as I'm new to PHP/MySql..Sorry

```
<?php
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

$id=$_GET['id'];
$ipuser=getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

//Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("localhost", "", "")or die("cannot connect to server"); 
mysql_select_db("")or die("cannot select DB");;
$querycheck="SELECT streamitem_id FROM on_streamdata WHERE streamitem_id='$id'";
$resultcheck=mysql_query($querycheck);
$num=mysql_numrows($resultcheck);
if ($num==0) {
?>
<br>Comment not found.<br>
<br><br>
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a><br>
<?
} else {
$ip=mysql_result($resultcheck,0,"streamitem_id");
if ($ip==$ipuser) {

?>
<form method="post">
<p align="center">
Are you sure you want to delete this comment?
<input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="1">
<br>
<input type="Submit" value="Delete">
</form>
<?
$confirm=$_POST['confirm'];

if ($confirm==1) {


$query=" DELETE streamitem_id FROM on_streamdata WHERE streamitem_id='$id'";
mysql_query($query);
echo "<br>Comment Deleted.<br>";

?>
<br><br>
<a href="javascript: history.go(-2)">Back</a><br>
<?
} else {

?>
<br><br>
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a><br>
<?
}

} else {
?>
<br>You are not allowed to delete this comment.<br>
<br><br>
<a href="javascript: history.go(-1)">Back</a><br>
<?
}
}
mysql_close();
```

Comment: Ugh, you're completely open to SQL injection...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first you don't pass any variable via the url query string here

```
echo '<a href="mysiteraw/sn-extend/theme/default/delete.php?PUT_SOME_NAME_HERE='.$streamitem_data['streamitem_id'].'" onclick="show_confirm() alt="Delete" title="Delete" class="delete">X</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
```

Hint: on next page you search for `$_GET['id']`, so I presume you should put `id` instead of `PUT_SOME_NAME_HERE` in above example :)

Try that and share results.

In your code example, there is also missing database selection and passing of mysql user/password. Do you remove them in purpose just to not show sensitive information here?

Comment: I added the above and still says 'no comment found' The code above is what I have found on the net. I don't know if its missing anything or if I've even filled in anything correct. That is what I need help with tbh.

The connect database pass, user, database I removed for security yes.

Comment: @David this is also wrong `$num=mysql_numrows($resultcheck);` It should be `$num=mysql_num_rows($resultcheck);`. Can you give also the mysql info? Table name/column names?

Comment: After changing that, it says this 'You are not allowed to delete this comment.' I wonder why? 

Is it something to do with this I have no clue what Ip has to do with it

$ip=mysql_result($resultcheck,0,"streamitem_id");
if ($ip==$ipuser) {

Comment: Please add `echo 'Paste this => '.$ip.' => '.$ipuser.'<br />';` before `if ($ip == $ipuser)`. And past the output here.

Comment: Ok it pastes the comment id and my ip. But stills states I'm not allowed to delete the any given comment I want to delete. I'm missing something obviously. Maybe user permissions or something

Comment: Passes your IP and comment's ID? If that's  true, this is the mistake. As you can see, the script is looking for equal values, so you comapre your ip to comment's id, you will always get error. The thing which I give you early returns both same things or two different? Also, which of the columns in on_streamdata holds IP, because it's not clear from the table structure?

Comment: It doesn't contain ip at all. I found this delete page on the net. 


The below prints the comment id
'.$ip.' => 

and the below prints my ip
'.$ipuser.'

Should it be finding the creator of the post? 

Because in my table this is the creator value  'streamitem_creator'

Comment: Well, no. IT will still compare your ip to some id which is not ip. Entire logic of `$ip == $ipuser` is invalid if there isn't saved ip in the table. You may try to output the `$_SESSION` and check if there is some sort of user id or something close to that. So you can compare your (I presume logged in) id to the one in your table. However, this make me think, that if administrator tries to delete something and that script allow only the author of the post to delete, that even the administrator will not be able to do it. Bottom line is that this script is full with errors.

Comment: Stream_creator is the user_id and yes I'm logged in. Will this work? If not, can I just add Ip into the table? 
And I don't really have an admin account set up. Its a basic user account atm. I've started building admin area, but concentrating on the frontend atm.

Comment: I'd also like to add that I'm thankful for so much time you're giving up to help. I'm really glad to find someone that is willing to help and explains the process in a mature manner. :) Your time is appreciated greatly.

Comment: If you create a field to hold your IP, than you should updated your scripts to insert such when you add a post. If you want to make it work as it's now, than you should (1) remove the check IP against Creator's ID, or (2) set the logged in user in session and update the script to compare Creator's ID against Logged in user.

Comment: I'd go with number two. Can you maybe write that up quickly? I have no clue what I'm doing in all honesty. I want it to be right. Sorry to be cheeky, just tell me to hop on if not. ;)

Comment: (1) go to the login page (2) when you enter username/password and submit the form, I presume there is some script which checks them and if they are valid, you are logged in, if not, display the form again. Anyway, tell me which table and what columns that table have. I'm looking for the logged in user, so if the table have 10+ fields, just see which one is the user's id and give me the column name.

Comment: The table is on_users and its user_id there is also user level if this helps user_level

Comment: You need to add something like thins `$_SESSION['user_id']=$row['user_id']; $_SESSION['user_level']=$row['user_level'];` Of course this is only an example which you should make it work with your query logic and get proper results to set into the SESSION. And I hope you will be able to figure it out or someone else to help you, since I'm off now, sorry.

Comment: I have got it working, thank you so much for all your help. You've helped one person :)

Comment: Good to hear. It's good to accept an response, because people here like when their solutions are accepted and also increase the chance of you getting more responses next time when you ask. It's a bit strange, but that's the truth... All the best!

Comment: Agreed, it also means that your help is worth the time you put in. Once again thank you. :)

Comment: By "accept" a response I had in mind clicking the checkbox on left of the accepted solution post :)

Answer (score 0):

`$querycheck="SELECT streamitem_id FROM on_streamdata WHERE streamitem_id='$id'";`

your table name is actually `on_groups_streamdata`

also, you need to sanitize and validate your input, or use PDO

Comment: Apologies, I inputted the wrong SQL table into here, I also have streamitem_id under my groups aswell as my on_streamdata table, I've updated it. Thanks